# NSNumber == nil in NSPredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I'm trying select values by property with type NSNumber, if property==intValue or property==nil.
But this code ignores values with property==nil.
What the point?

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
        @"(ANY region.beacons.major == %d OR ANY region.beacons.major == nil) 
        AND (ANY region.beacons.minor == %d OR ANY region.beacons.minor == nil)",
        rangedBeacon.major.intValue, rangedBeacon.minor.intValue];
```

[image]

Comment: Use `=` instead of `==` for nil

Comment: No, some another reason ...

Comment: `nil` not `NIL`

Comment: I tried both way and both don't work.